# magento 2 create xml file of orders and send them via email programmatically

Tags: magento2

In Magento2 how can I create XML files for orders and send them via email programmatically. Please suggest.

Comment: on each order place ?

Comment: Can you elaborate please? You want a cut off like thing? For example at a certain hour get all the orders that are processing, create a csv or xml with all of them and send it via email? is that it?